# how to post an image file in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, file, dart, dart-pub

jsonEncode({  MultipartFile.fromFile(filepath, filename: ' fileName')});

Myerror-
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: LinkedHashSet len:1

Comment: why do you want to `jsonEncode` an object of type `MultipartFile`?

Comment: because the API only accept file type. thank you for your time

Comment: what exactly does it accept?

Comment: its an image with filetype. not base64 image

Comment: post a real example how json should look like, "image with filetype" does not really say much

Comment: image of sign cavas  |file| : select files ...

Comment: what should the json look like?

Comment: 'doctor_sign_image'=@"/path/to/file"'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

File imageFile = new File(imageFilePath);
List<int> imageBytes = imageFile.readAsBytesSync();
String base64Image = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

to post an image without base64 encoding

```
final data = FormData.fromMap({
  'image_media': await MultipartFile.fromFile(
     imagePath,
      filename: filename),
});
try {
  final response =
      await this._dio.post('url', data: data);
  return response;}
```